# UILabel.layer not being retained out of for loop scope

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, calayer, quartz-graphics

I've got a loop making some UILabels and adding their .layers to a CALayer I'm rendering offscreen to a context for a UIImage that I present later (BTW: I'm doing this rendering on another queue before passing back to main.)

If I do it in the loop like this:

```
for (i=0; i<offlineModel.modelArray.count; i++) {

    UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [newLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:9.0]];
    [newLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:76/255.0 green:76/255.0 blue:78/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    [newLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [newLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];
    [newLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [newLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [newLabel setNumberOfLines:0];

    [newLabel setText:[(LVBarGraphModelPair *)[offlineModel.modelArray objectAtIndex:i] xValue]];
    [newLabel setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, barWidth+barSpacing, 3*8.0)];
    [newLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:NO];
    [newLabel sizeToFit];

    CGPoint center = CGPointMake((((offlineModel.modelArray.count-i-1)*barSpacing)+placeholderBarContainerLayerRect.origin.x+(.5*barWidth)), placeholderBarContainerLayerRect.size.height);

    [newLabel setCenter:center];
    [newLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(lroundf(newLabel.frame.origin.x), lroundf(placeholderBarContainerLayerRect.origin.y + placeholderBarContainerLayerRect.size.height+LVBARGRAPH_BAR_ANIMATION_XAXIS_LABELS_OFFSET_X), newLabel.frame.size.width, newLabel.frame.size.height)];

    [layer addSublayer:newLabel.layer];
}
```

I get black rects where the labels should be:
[image: Black Rects instead of labels]
So to troubleshoot I make one instead of 6 by just removing the loop (same code):

```
    UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [newLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:9.0]];
    [newLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:76/255.0 green:76/255.0 blue:78/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    [newLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [newLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];
    [newLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [newLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [newLabel setNumberOfLines:0];

    [newLabel setText:[(LVBarGraphModelPair *)[offlineModel.modelArray objectAtIndex:i] xValue]];
    [newLabel setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, barWidth+barSpacing, 3*8.0)];
    [newLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:NO];
    [newLabel sizeToFit];

    CGPoint center = CGPointMake((((offlineModel.modelArray.count-i-1)*barSpacing)+placeholderBarContainerLayerRect.origin.x+(.5*barWidth)), placeholderBarContainerLayerRect.size.height);

    [newLabel setCenter:center];
    [newLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(lroundf(newLabel.frame.origin.x), lroundf(placeholderBarContainerLayerRect.origin.y + placeholderBarContainerLayerRect.size.height+LVBARGRAPH_BAR_ANIMATION_XAXIS_LABELS_OFFSET_X), newLabel.frame.size.width, newLabel.frame.size.height)];

    [layer addSublayer:newLabel.layer];
```

[image: Without loop it shows up!]

And there it is! What is going on?

I need the loop so I can have a variable number of these.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [`CATextLayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CATextLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) instead of creating `UILabel` and using their layer.

Comment: It's a subclass of `CALayer`, so yes it does (see the `shadowXXX` properties of `CALayer`).

Comment: Wait, that would make a TEXT shadow?

Comment: Well I didn't try but yes it should: the shadows drawn usually corresponds to the opaque content of the layer, not the layer bounding box. CoreGraphics behaves this way ([see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadows/dq_shadows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH208-TPXREF101)) and CALayers does the same too (seen [documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/LayerVisProps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006074-SW18)).

Comment: Could you kindly explain why UILabel doesn't work? Thanks!

Comment: Because only the reference to the layer is stored, not the UILabel itself? So if you had to use UILabels for some reason, the only way they would work is if you somehow ensured the UILabels survived outside the loop.